# VBA open user mailbox, search folder, select most recent email, save an attachment, open that attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

Ok, subject says most of it, hopefully my scrap of code will belie the detail.

```
Sub dSearchUserFolder()
'set rig email and filename root strings
addressee = "RigBig1.Drill@money.com"
subjectRoot = "Daily Drill"
wellId = "RM01-1-1"

Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

'open users inbox folder and search and select most recent

Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("coyrigs")
myRecipient.Resolve

If myRecipient.Resolved Then
Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderInbox)

'filter by addresse and subject (subjectRoot)
Items = inboxFolder.Items.Restrict(xxxxx)
'select most recent


'save attachment with filename matching "Daily Drilling*.pdf"

FileName = %HOME% & "/Dropbox/Drilling/" & wellId Format(Item.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
'open attachment


End Sub
```

I'm going to bash my way through to a solution one way or another through about a day or two of googling. I think this will be of interest to others as I can see from searching around a bunches of minor problems for newbs like me, hence I'm posting here. But if anyone out there wants to help, it'll be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there - call Items.Sort to sort by [ReceivedTime], then loop through the Items collection. For each MailItem objet, loop through attachments and call Attachment.SaveAsFile.